# SP2010 - Percentage Progress Bar

Tags: 2010

I'm using SP2010. I'm wondering about displaying some sort of progress bar which would show percentage of how many "things" are done.

To elaborate: a person in our organization needs to in process, do training, then qualify for the position they hold. Our management would like a way to track this.

I think some type of graphical display showing a progress bar would work well as a quick reference.

I figure I'd need to have separate columns in my list for each training portion, then do something with a calculated column to come up with the percentage. Then I need some way to graphically display this.

I would suspect I could make something work with `jQuery::Flot`, but don't know if there might be an easier way. Can anyone point me in a direction here or have a better method or can show me something they have done already?

I'm not opposed to something OOB, but have found most of the OOB stuff isn't so great for most of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully made a real progress bar for the percentage column using just `xsl` and `css` and *no javascript whatsoever*, and *no third party components*.  Just a dozen lines of code and it works perfectly.

[Look at this other SSE thread for a full description](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/120980/7452).

Comment: Sweetnesss! I'll have to run this at work, but it looks like what I was wanting. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!  I've done this now on two servers without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a bit late to the game with this one. I've made a similar graphical representation of progress using several columns previously:

[image: Multiple columns showing progress through approval]

Unfortunately it was to promote the use of our product; although it's possible to do similar things using jQuery or XSL.

Here's the article (on the company I work for's blog; promoting the use of our product):

[Pentalogic Blog: Thinking Sideways About Highlighter](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/09/thinking-sideways-about-highlighter/)

In the post I use a single source column, but you could use multiple fields in a similar manner  (even using a "Date completed" field for each step).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Looking at the page you sent, the "progress bar" is what I am looking for ... I wouldn't know how to implement at present though. I didn't see anything like it using jQuery, though I'm not fluent in it's use. I'll go play with it and see what I can come up with.