# XSL Handle on PercentComplete column

Tags: 2010, xslt

In my sharepoint task list there is a field with a display name of `% Completed` with a `name` of `PercentCompleted`.

I am trying to get an XSL handle on this column so I can add a css class.  I have put this is my [`fldtypes_custom.xsl`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424763/Zen-and-the-art-of-XSLT-rendering-fields-SharePoin) file in the `_layouts` folder where Sharepoint picks it up automatically.  My other XSL mods work, but this one won't take.

```
<!-- Convert Percentage Complete into progressbars    -->
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='PercentComplete']" mode="body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
    <span class="percentprogress"><span class="hiddenpercentage"><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></span></span>  
</xsl:template>
```

So it seems like I just don't have a proper hook.  I've tried changing the `mode` to `number` but that doesn't work.

Clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH!  I got it!  Funny how it happens that you find the answer *after* you give up and post a question.

I changed the mode to `number_body` and it hooked.

I also tweaked a few other things, in case anyone is looking for this.  When you fetch `currentvalue` you get something like `20 %` which won't compute in css.  So you have to used `translate()` to remove the spaces.  Also, you can't set the size properly using a `<span>` but you CAN do it with a `<div>`.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: xsl+css progressbar]

So here is a *completely javascript-less solution* to rendering percentage progress bars in sharepoint:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='PercentComplete']" mode="Number_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
    <xsl:variable name="percentvalue" select="translate($currentValue, ' ','') "/>      <!-- Remove the space so just have the number and the % sign -->

    <div class="percentprogress">
        <div class="innerpercentprogress" style="width:{$percentvalue}"><span><xsl:value-of select="$percentvalue" /></span></div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/*progress bar rendering for percentages; percentprogress=background - innerpercentprogress is the actual bar*/ 
.percentprogress{
    background-color: #2572BC;
}   
.innerpercentprogress{
    background-color: #7F94AA;
    border-right: red 2px solid;
    padding: 2px;
}
.innerpercentprogress span{
    color:#FFDD00;
    padding-left:2px;
}
```