# How to refresh after edits to fldtypes.xsl?

Tags: xslt, iis

After I make an edit to my custom `\LAYOUTS\XSL\fldtypes.xsl` file, [such as these](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/120980/7452), how do I make the system immediately load the new file?

I know I can get it loaded immediately with an `iisreset`.

I know that if I wait overnight, at some point the new xsl seems to get loaded without doing an `iisreset`.

But is there another way to do it without waiting and without an `iisreset`?

Comment: How are you deploying the XSLT file ?

Comment: It is just a custom `fldtypes.xsl` you just name it something like `fldtypes_custom.xsl` and leave in `LAYOUTS\XSL\` and Sharepoint reads and uses it.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424763/Zen-and-the-art-of-XSLT-rendering-fields-SharePoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to at minimum recycle the application pool so that SharePoint can cache the changes made to the file.

IISRESET will make sure the change get picked up for all the web applications.

Comment: So you say that just recycling the application pool is enough to get it to load for a particular site?  How long does it take?

Comment: It depends on the SharePoint server size and amount of customizations. In normal case recycling wont take more than 1 minute. Also you need to make sure you are recycling all Front End Servers.