# How to Add External xsl Stylesheet to DispForm.aspx

Tags: xslt, display-form

It isn't too difficult to use xsl to [modify the display of items](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120974/xsl-handle-on-percentcomplete-column) in a list (via a custom `fldtypes.xsl` file), but can the `fldtypes.xsl` file also be used to change the display on the `dispform.aspx' ?

For example, I created an [xsl modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977990/xsl-partial-match-on-name) that converts phone numbers into callto links within the listviews.

But I would like the phone numbers in the fields of the `dispform.aspx` to also pick up on the same modifications.  Can I do this somehow with the `fldtypes.xsl`?

*[later]*

Anyone got a clue here?

**[waaay later]**

I just posted a new question and then noticed I already asked it a long time ago (this question), so I am updating it now.

Sharepoint Lists all use my custom `fldtypes.xsl` page for style modifications. How do I make my `DispForm.aspx` page also use the same xsl style sheet? I know I could edit the form itself and modify the xsl within, but I want it to pull from the styles I've already created.

Now, DispForm.aspx contains it's own xsl stylesheet, but can I use my custom one too?

How do I hook up the external xsl stylesheet to `DispForm.aspx`?

I've tried to add `<xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/fldtypes_custom.xsl"/>` within the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tags. But it doesn't seem to load anything.

So I've found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931697/xslt-stylesheet-parameters-in-imported-stylesheets) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300749/insert-xml-stylesheet-tag-with-xsl) with examples, but where do I put the link inside the `DispForm.aspx` page and still be able to use the existing xsl as an override?